# Build Entity Form Url

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

a Microsoft CRM 2011 question. Given the following parameters:

- An entity schema name (i.e. opportunity, new_customentity)
- An entity guid
- A CRM organization base url (i.e. http://myhost.com/ORGNAME/)

How can I build an url to point to the main (or "default") form of that record?

I can tell a pattern in form urls, but some querystring params are pretty obscure and I wouldn't know how to reuse them for any other kind of entity. In addition, version 4.0 had specific URLs (/sfa/, etc) for system entities. It doesn't seem to be the case anymore.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks.

(additional tags welcome, I cannot add them.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx), the format would be:

```
http://myhost.com/ORGNAME/main.aspx?etn={ENTITYNAME}&pagetype=entityrecord&id={ENTITYGUID}
```

Replace `{ENTITYNAME}` and `{ENTITYGUID}` with your values.

Comment: Better to use safe ASCII adresses, so
`{` -> `%7B`,
`}` -> `%7D`.