# Get Dynamics CRM Contact Link from URL to MS Access

Tags: ms-access, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am trying to find out a way to match Account names in MS Access Table and Dynamics CRM Account list and pull the contacts listed under the account into MSAccess .

E.g.

MS access Table: **AccountContacts**

```
CompanyName      Contact   CRMLink
TavernCompany    --         --
```

CRM Account Entity

```
 Account Name: Tavern Company
 Contact1:      Chad M Last
 Contact2:      Miller L Light
```

So I am trying to pull the links of Contact1 so the resulting Access Table will be

```
CompanyName      Contact           CRMLink
TavernCompany    Chad M Last       http://Somethinghered&pagetype=entityrecord
```

The Idea is users of Access must be able to click on the link and View the contact in Dynamics CRM

Any info regarding connecting Access with CRM will be helpful.

Comment: May be of interest http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/132223-Linking-Access-to-MS-Dynamics-CRM

Comment: This will answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899842/build-entity-form-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MSDN, the format would be:

```
http://myhost.com/ORGNAME/main.aspx?etn={ENTITYNAME}&pagetype=entityrecord&id={ENTITYGUID}
```

Replace `{ENTITYNAME}` and `{ENTITYGUID}` with  values.