# How to form URL for different entity in Dynamics 365?

Tags: url, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I am building up url for different entity in **Dynamics 365** crm. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899842/build-entity-form-url) for **crm 2011** but I want more elaborate solution than that.

**Observed URL:**

**For Quote Entity:** `https:**[instance url]**.com/main.aspx?etc=1084&extraqs=&histKey=254156564&id=%7b[**GUID**]%7d&newWindow=true&pagetype=entityrecord&sitemappath=SFA%7cCollateral%7cnav_quotes#765575448`

**For Order Entity:** `https:**[instance url]**.com/main.aspx?etc=1088&extraqs=&histKey=653905533&id=%7b[**GUID**]%7d&newWindow=true&pagetype=entityrecord&sitemappath=SFA%7cCollateral%7cnav_orders#817364929`

I created other url for other entities and observed the query parameter value of the url as like below:
 1. **etc** is constant for different entity. eg. for quote(1084) and order(1088)
 2. **extraqs** is empty.
 3. **histKey** is variable for an entity. It is appearing in different value for a same entity record.
 4. **id** is the unique identifier of a record (i have no question about this)
 5. **sitemappath** is different for different entity.

Now I want to know about - 
1. what is **etc** and why it remains same for a entity always? 
 
2. what is **histKey**(why it gives random value every time) and **sitemappath**?

Comment: Are you doing this on CRM 2011? "etc" is [entity type code](https://spandcrm.com/2017/08/14/dynamics-365-entity-type-code-list/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are using these in our Dynamics 365 CRM application without issues. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/open-forms-views-dialogs-reports-url)

Simple record form using **etc** (entity type code):

```
https://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etc=1&id=%7b[GUID]%7d&pagetype=entityrecord
```

Same record using **etn** (entity type name):

```
https://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etn=account&id=%7b[GUID]%7d&pagetype=entityrecord
```

Same record in **UCI**:

```
https://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/apps/appname/main.aspx?etc=1&id=%7b[GUID]%7d&pagetype=entityrecord
```

Particular form using **formid**:

```
https://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etc=1&id=%7b[GUID]%7d&pagetype=entityrecord&extraqs=formid%3d[formGUID]
```

`sitemap` can be ignored as the `pagetype` param will render the top navigation bar & `histkey` can also be ignored as its for internal platform/browser usage for previous/forward navigation. `extraqs` is any extra query string param you want to pass that pre-populate the form attribute.

```
https://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etc=1&id=%7b[GUID]%7d&pagetype=entityrecord&extraqs=fullname%3DNew%20Contact
```

Documentation says:

> Do not use the etc (entity type code) parameter that contains an integer code for the entity. This integer code varies for custom entities in different organizations

But if you are not creating a custom entity directly in any non-development environment, only the solution is being used to port the customizations across different environment then that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Power Pane Chrome addon which is a helper tool , help you to show entities urls

Answer (score 1):

To open a Particular Record for Account Entity, Where etn is Entity Schema name.

```
http://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etn=account&pagetype=entityrecord&id=%7B91330924-802A-4B0D-A900-34FD9D790829%7D
```

For Example you have a Custom Entity let's call it Account Plan and your entity schema name is new_accountplan, so your url will be something like below

```
http://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etn=new_accountplan&pagetype=entityrecord&id=%7B81440924-802A-4B0D-A900-34FD9D790829%7D
```

Similar way to open a particular Form for user to fill information

```
https://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etc=1&id=%7b[GUID]%7d&pagetype=entityrecord&extraqs=formid%3d[formGUID]
```